# Compare two distributions with varying focus on different regions

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, entropy, cross-correlation, kullback-leibler

I have been trying to find if my problem matches has been discussed in prior research and if any technique exists to solve it.

Here's the problem:

Given two distributions (pdf) D1 and D2 over a space X. 
I can compare them by using cross-entropy to determine the extent to which they differ. In doing so, cross-entropy (or related metrics such as RCE etc) assume that each point of X is of equal significance. What if that’s not true? That is, say I know that the significance of different points on X isn’t the same, and we have a distribution say H that captures the importance of each point in X. How can I compare D1 and D2 while giving more importance to the points (regions) that are more important, and less to points that are less?

I have multiple questions based on this.

1. Has anyone encountered/solved this before? Any ideas on how I could proceed?
2. I can think of some hacky solutions (multiply significance for each point with cross entropy associated with the point). But this doesn't seem principled (ie why multiply with the weight -- call this w_i -- and not say log(w_i) or exp(w_i)?

Comment: @chet: I think the answer to your question is to use a weighted variant of the KL divergence. The base KL is: KL(p,q) = \int p log p / q. If you know want to rebalance the space, you can do so by considering $\tilde {D1} = H D1$. Don't forget to renormalize the distributions, otherwise the KL divergence doesnt have to be positive anymore

Answer (score 0):

You could use some weighted variant of KL (Kullback-Leibler) divergence. Such is proposed and used in the following paper [ON WEIGHTED KULLBACK-LEIBLER DIVERGENCE
FOR DOUBLY TRUNCATED RANDOM VARIABLES](https://www.ine.pt/revstat/pdf/ONWEIGHTEDKULLBACK-LEIBLER.pdf) (note that their notation is strange.)

Alternative, a weighted version of some other statistical divergence or distance.